# Javascript get value from array error

Tags: javascript

I need some help! Im retrieving some values from mySQL database using an external  'grabber'.

```
<?php 
    $datapiechart = file_get_contents("url which retrieves the values from MySQL"); 
?>
```

Which results in:

```
[{ "Name1": 62, "Name2": 42, "Name3": 19, "Name4": 7, "Name5": 6, "Name6": 4, "Name7": 1, "Name8": 4, "Name9": 3, "Name10": 1, "Name11": 1, "Name12": 0 }]
```

Then I want to select the values in this array.

```
<SCRIPT>
       dataObjectdatapiechart = <?php echo $datapiechart; ?>
</SCRIPT>

<script>  dataObjectdatapiechart.Name1</script>
```

I don't get whats going wrong here.

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting, we can't know what's wrong if you don't state it.

Comment: use array dataObjectdatapiechart[0],dataObjectdatapiechart[1] etc...

Answer (score 1):

`dataObjectdatapiechart` is an array (with only one element), so you need to access it's contents using an indexer:

```
var item = dataObjectdatapiechart[0]; // Retrieve the object from the array
var name1 = item.Name1;
var name2 = item.Name2;
var name3 = item.Name3;
//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`dataObjectdatapiechart[0].Name1`

The Object `{ "Name1": 62, "Name2": 42, "Name3": 19, "Name4": 7, "Name5": 6, "Name6": 4, "Name7": 1, "Name8": 4, "Name9": 3, "Name10": 1, "Name11": 1, "Name12": 0 }`

is at 0th position of the array.